# XSS attack in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, security, xss

I am developing a WordPress theme. for the security of it with XSS. here i have two queries:

> 1. How to detect theme can be infected with XSS attack? or already infected?
> 2. How to prevent it to be infected with XSS?

i know this is related to WordPress and i should post this on WordPress. i did already [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/190198/how-to-prevent-xss-attack-in-wordpress-theme) but no solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

XSS isn't an infection, it's a type of security vulnerability. You can [learn more about preventing XSS vulnerabilities here](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/06/preventing-xss-vulnerabilities-in-php-everything-you-need-know).

> 1. How to detect theme can be infected with XSS attack? or already infected?

There isn't an easy answer to this question. To determine if a theme is vulnerable to XSS attacks, you need to audit every source file and check every place that output is generated to make sure it's not doing anything dangerous (e.g. `<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">`).

> 2. How to prevent it to be infected with XSS?

1. **Always escape output to prevent user-provided data from adding HTML entities**, such as `<`, `>`, etc. A quick helper method to use here is:

   ```
   function noHTML($input, $encoding='UTF-8')
   {
       return htmlspecialchars($input, ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, $encoding);
   }
   ```

   Note that this will prevent users from supplying any HTML at all.
2. Use a library such as [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org) to escape entire blocks of HTML to prevent XSS attacks.